# Sudden disconnection of second screen and usb keyboard - Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb, keyboard, multiple-monitors

**Hardware:**

Lenovo Thinkpad x250 with Dokingstation

Intel® Core™ i5-5300U CPU @ 2.30GHz × 4,
Mesa Intel® HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2),
64 Bit

External Keyboard connected via USB (Dokingstation)
Second Screen connected with VGA (Dokingstation),
Ubuntu 20.04

**Problem:**

Suddenly the extended (second) Screen disconnects and so does the USB-Keyboard and the Mouse. This happens sometimes 2 min. sometimes 20 min. or more after Startup while working and on the ext. Screen "No Signal" appears. The primary Screen and Keyboard on the Notebook keeps on working fine. The Mouse is connected through USB to the Dokingstation too, but the mouse keeps on being connected and then a minute or so later disconnects, and this repeats constantly. Sometimes the Keyboard is reconnected some times for longer disconnected. The ext. Screen never reconnects.

I did switch from gdm3 to lightdm, but no change.

This happened since the Update from 19.10 to 20.04.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I swiped the Harddrive, made a fresh installation with 20.04 and all is working fine now. So the Live-Update from 19.10 to 20.04 may have not worked thoroughly fine. So doing it by iso may work also for others.